# I am trying to call an action result method though C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a action result method i would like to run. How can i call it though C# code?

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id, string error)
        {
           ....
        }
```

Comment: `var result = someInstanceOfTheController.Edit(someInteger, someString);`  It's just a method on a class, just like any other method on any other class.

Comment: I'm assuming there is more to your question that you're letting us know, in which case, more precision is welcome. Otherwise just call the method on an instance of the object that owns it...

Comment: To what end? To render the output the ActionResult would create?

Comment: This will be there in controller page of the view

Comment: I tried var result = ContractController.Edit(contractInstance.SalesContractId, ""); But its not liking it.

Comment: I have another action result running code, if certian things match up, i would like to break and swtich to this action controller. Thats what i'm trying to do. Whould this be a bad thing to do?

Comment: Then you need `return RedirectToAction("ActionName","ControllerName")`

Comment: Thanks let me check it out :)

Comment: How would i put it? return RedirectToAction(Edit(contractInstance.SalesContractId, ""), ContractController); This is not working ...

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = contractInstance.SalesContractId, error = ""});

Comment: Thanks looks like its fitting let me test it :)

Comment: Sweet guys thanks +1 to Wahid Bitar and Chips :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = contractInstance.SalesContractId, error = ""});
```

To open action on a new page, you need to add html attribute, and controller name into yor action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "TypeControllerName", new { id = contractInstance.SalesContractId, error = ""}, new {target = "_blank"})
```

Comment: Sure if you could try tel me how i would open a RedirectToAction on a new page? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11034159/1356321

Comment: let me know, if you get an issue on my suggested actionlink, please also up-vote :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a page with the same name for that controller, it should automatically call the action when that page is loaded.

So if you have Edit.cshtml that action should be called.