# I would like the return of an ActionResult displayed on a new page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like the return of my ActionResult Displayed on a new page?

This call below is the only call i have not been able to display on a new page?

Can any one show me what to add to get this right, i have used Window.open with buttons but now i have a RedirectToAction.

**This is the call i want displayed on a new page/window:**

```
return RedirectToAction("Print", new { id = contractInstance.SalesContractId });
```

**I have buttons already doing this with this code:**

```
window.open('Contract/Print/' + $(this).attr('id'));
```

**The Print actionResult looks as follows:**

```
public ActionResult Print(int id) // sales contract Id
        {
            ParameterFields paramFields = CreateParameterFields(id); // pass the id of the contract
            // Save the report run details
            Guid reportRunId;
            SaveReportRunDetails(paramFields, out reportRunId);               

            try
            {

               <<< Print code >>>
//Open a new page on this return would also be a good answer :)!!!!!!!
                return File(arrStream, "application/pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = err.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = id, error = err.Message }); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Every thing is working, but i would like my print on a new page or tab, how can i get that RedirectToAction displayed on a new page??

Comment: Something like:  return RedirectToAction(window.open("Edit", new { id = id, error = err.Message }));

Comment: You're mixing client-side scripting with sever side code.

Comment: In the comment yes, but i was trying to show u what i'm trying to accomplish :)

Comment: So if the print action throws an exception, you want the exception to open the Edit view in a new window? _Why_?

Comment: Ok forget that one lol sorry, its just an example, the one im trying to redirect is, :return RedirectToAction("Print", new { id = contractInstance.SalesContractId });

Comment: Or even the return File(arrStream, "application/pdf"); i can open a new page there, I just need to know how to open a new window.

Comment: How does your action get called? if it's through a link you can apply  target=”_blank” on the link itself(that will be static of course, before the action runs => it will always open in new window)

Answer (score 2):

How are you getting to the Print action from your Views?  Is it just a hyperlink `@Html.ActionLink("Print", "Print")`?

.NET cannot tell your browser to open a new window from the server, that is done client side via the HTML markup or javascript calls (eg. Window.Open).  The easiest way to open a link in a new page is to specify the target attribute on the HTML.  Using the ActionLink helper, your syntax would be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Print", "Print", "Contract", new{id = Model.SalesContractId}, new {target = "_blank"})
```

This should render something like this:

```
<a href="/Contract/Print/4" target="_blank">Print</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try following in controller action

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>
                    window.open('YourViewName', '_blank');
                </script>");
```

Thanks
Subraatam